# Is it possible to attach a qtip2 tooltip to each option of an HTML select drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip, qtip2

Using a browser's native tooltips, I can easily attach tooltips to each option of a SELECT element. i.e, in the following example, when I hover over each option, I get the corresponding tooltip("Option1" for the first etc...):

```
<select  id='test_dd' name='options'>
    <option title='Option1' value='1' >Option1</option>
    <option title='Option2' value='2' >Option2</option>
    <option title='Option3' value='3' >Option3</option>
</select>
```

But if I try to do this with Qtip, e.g by adding the following to the bottom of my HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $('[title]').qtip(); </script>
```

I can't get any tooltip to show next to the options (qtip is properly installed and the paths are correct - I get tooltips to show up fie on other elements with this setup).
Reading this this link http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=3630 , it seems it can't be done , unless you change the default SELECT element to a custom one?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. Some browsers, notably IE, don't register events on `<option>` tags. Apart from just styling, this is another reason a lot of `<select>` replacement plugins have been created

Comment: It seems possible (even in IE) using native tooltips

Comment: well go ahead then...why did you ask question? Ever try to bind a mouse event to an `<option>` tag in IE, or hide an `<option>` in IE? Can't do it...not supported. Plugin requires binding events to the tag

Comment: I asked because I want to use the added features of Qtip. Your original answer did not make it clear that it was an issue with the way the plugin implements tooltips (i.e that it requires binding events to tags), and implied it was not possible to get tooltips on IE, period. It's possible to answer questions without the nasty attitude, you know.

Comment: wasn't trying to be nasty...I got impression you didn't like being told what it seems you already knew. I explained in my answer why it couldn't be done